# Drawing Curves on Surfaces in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, calculus

Well, the title pretty much states it.  I want to be able to draw a curve on a surface in Web GL.  So for example, I'd like to draw a parabola on the surface of a sphere.

x = cos(theta)sin(phi); y = sin(theta)sin(phi); z = cos(phi).

If you make theta = theta(t) and phi = phi(t), you can draw curves on the surface.

I guess lines on shapes is what I need.  Anyone know if that's possible in Web GL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parabola is the set of point of the plane that have the same distance from a line and a point (called focus). The point here is what do you mean by "line" on a sphere. Remember that a parabola extends to infinity, bu you can't do that on a sphere, unless you define some particular metric on it.

Anyway, you gave use a parametrization of the sphere, in terms on theta and phi. That's good. If you want to define a curve on the surface, you should have a bind between theta and phi, for example

```
phi = theta ^ 2
```

would draw something that could be defined as a "parabola" in some way, i.e. the projection on the sphere, given by the parametrization, of its representation on a plane.

Comment: oh ok, I should have been more specific.  What I mean by 'line' is a closed curve on the surface of some shape.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing, you have to begin from the parametrization of the surface. The parametrization gives you a way to split your surface into small flat shapes that you put in the Euclidean 3D space to recreate the surface. In all those shapes you should draw your piece of line. As for closed curves, they should either be closed on the region of the plane that is projected onto the surface, or they must match coordinates on opposing borders. I never coded for WebGL, one day I'll try it, but I can give you just some theory for now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for help with how to do this in WebGL? In this case, take a look at this example

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17612367/OpenGL%20to%20WebGL/example%202.3.1%20-%20line%20graph/code/index.html

you would basically load the positions into a vector and draw it using drawArrays with LINELOOP or something... See this cheatsheet for arguments or google the drawArrays function for more info:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/webgl_cheat_sheet/WebGL_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Good Luck!